# Can I stop the "this website does not supply identity information" message

Tags: security, https

I have a site which is completely on https: and works well, but, some of the images served are from other sources e.g. ebay, or Amazon.

This causes the browser to prompt a message: "**this website does not supply identity information**"

How can I avoid this? The images must be served from elsewhere sometimes.

Comment: Which browser are you using? And does it really automatically prompt you, or do you mean when hovering or clicking the favicon in the address bar?

Comment: Hi! Firefox and yeah, I mean if you hover its there

Comment: The accepted answer is wrong. See @EdNdee's answer for the correct answer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Firefox shows the message

> "This website does not supply identity information."

while hovering or clicking the favicon (Site Identity Button) when

- you requested a page over HTTP
- you requested a page over HTTPS, but the page contains mixed passive content

#### HTTP

HTTP connections generally don't supply any reliable identity information to the browser. That's normal. HTTP was designed to simply transmit data, not to secure the data it transmits.

On server side you could only avoid that message, if the server would start using a SSL certificate and the code of the page would be changed to exclusively use HTTPS requests.

To avoid the message on client side you could enter `about:config` in the address bar, confirm you'll be careful and set `browser.chrome.toolbar_tips = false`.

#### HTTPS, mixed passive content

When you request a page over HTTPS from a site which is using a SSL certificate, the site *does* supply identity information to the browser and normally the message wouldn't appear.

But if the requested page embeds at least one `<img>`, `<video>`, `<audio>` or `<object>` element which includes content over HTTP (which won't supply identity information), than you'll get a so-called *mixed passive content* <sup>*</sup> situation.

Firefox won't block mixed passive content by default, but only show said message to warn the user.

To avoid this on server side, you'd first need to identify which requests are producing mixed content.

With Firefox on Windows you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> (Control-Option-K on Mac) to open the web console, deactivate the css, js and security filters, and press <kbd>F5</kbd> to reload the page, to show all the requests of the page.

Then fix your code for each line which is showing "mixed content", i.e. change the appropriate parts of your code to use `https://` or, depending on your case, [protocol-relative URLs](http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/).

If the external site an element is requested from doesn't use a SSL certificate, the only chance to avoid the message would be to copy the external content over to your site so your code can refer to it locally via HTTPS.

---

<sub>* Firefox also knows *mixed **active** content*, which is blocked by default, but that's another story.</sub>

Comment: This answer is wrong, It has nothing to do with mixed content at all, it's solely about validation via an EV cert, as per @EdNdee's answer. Personally I wouldn't worry about it. Most people consider the EV certification as simply a money spinner for issuers.

Comment: As stated above, this answer is wrong. When mixed content is served, the message indicates that that's what happened: "Parts of this page are not secure (such as images)."

Comment: This answer is wrong, and the comments above describe what, why and how. To add one of my own -- mixed content has little to do with verifying ownership. I have a Web page here served over HTTPS with no mixed content linked, and Firefox, for one, still tells me "website does not supply ownership information".

Comment: This SO page currently shows the message and all resources are delivered via HTTPS so that's not necessarily true. Is there any evidence to back this up?

Answer (score 35):

"This website does not supply identity information." is not only about the encryption of the link to the website itself but also the identification of the operators/owners of the website - just like it actually says. For that warning (it's not really an error) to stop, I believe you have to apply for the Extended Validation Certificate https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate. EVC rigorously validates the entity behind the website not just the website itself.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. "this website does not supply identity/ownership information" warnings are do to the HTTPS site not using EVCs. It's not due, as I interpret the other post, to mixed content issues. Firefox will show a shield icon if there're mixed content issues. Firefox shows a green name of the owner when the site uses EVCs.

Comment: @Geremia I got this warning after switching a site to https but where some img src links were remaining to be http in the html source, regardless that the server made a redirection for them in the actual connection to https. After I rewrote all these hyperlinks, the error ceased to appear and a lock icon appears instead. I have never seen the shield icon on the site. I used firefox 37.0.2 here. Certainly the error message's wording appears to be for what you've said, however, this was what happened to me.

Answer (score 0):

Jürgen Thelen's answer is absolutely correct. If the images (quite often the case) displayed on the page are served over "http" the result will be exactly as described no matter what kind of cert you have, EV or not.  This is very common on e-commerce sites due to the way they're constructed. I've encountered this before on my own site AND CORRECTED IT by simply making sure that no images have an "http" address - and this was on a site that did not have an EV cert. Use the ctrl +shift +K process that Jürgen describes and it will point you to the offending objects. If the path to an object is hard coded and the image resides on your server (not called from somewhere else) simply remove the "http://servername.com" and change it to a relative path instead. Correct that and the problem will go away.  Note that the problem may be in one of the configuration files as well, such as one of the config.php files.

The real issue is that Firefox's error message is misleading and has nothing to do with whether the SSL is an EV cert or not. It really means there is mixed content on the page but doesn't say that. A couple of weeks ago I had a site with the same problem and Firefox displayed the no-identity message.  Chrome, however, (which I normally don't use) displayed an exclamation mark instead of a lock. I clicked on it and it said the cert was valid (with a green dot), it was a secure connection (another green dot), AND had "Mixed Content. The site includes HTTP resources" which was entirely accurate and the source of the problem (with a red dot). Once the offending paths were changed to relative paths, the error messages in both Firefox and Chrome disappeared.

Comment: While this might be correct it's only part of the issue.  Saying that it "has nothing to do with whether the SSL is an EV cert or not" is not true.  I have a secure site with absolutely NO mixed content and I get this warning simply because it's not an EV cert.  There are multiple possible causes to this issue that need to be considered.

Comment: I second BrianVPS's comment. Test it for yourself… Create a test page on a domain with a valid Let's Encrypt certificate, with no images or other linked content whatsoever… Sure enough, you still get the 'website does not supply ownership information' message. Reloading the page with the network monitor open confirms that all the requests are https.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was a problem of mixed content. I forced everything to make HTTPS requests on the page and it fixed the problem.
For people who come here from Google search, you can use Cloudflare's (free) page rules to accomplish this without touching your source code. Use the "Always use HTTPS" setting for your domain.

Answer (score -4):

You can also transfrom http links to https links using url shortener www.tr.im. That is the only URL-shortener I found that provides shorter links through https.
You just have to change it manually from `http://tr.im/xxxxxx` to `https://tr.im/xxxxxx`.